# rotation around point not working ue4

Tags: rotation, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to rotate a sphere around the center of another sphere, but I cannot make it work. I tried setActorLocation before and it also wouldn't work.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

[main buleprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRcNI.jpg)
[RotateAround blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEJRZ.jpg)

Comment: Are the rotated sphere set to "Movable"? https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Actors/Mobility/

Comment: Yes, I verified it.

Comment: looking at your images - why is in function `RotateAround` center multiplied by local rotation vector? Simply adding makes more sense to me. Also, presuming that **Sphere** is centered in origin `(0,0,0)`, result multiplication is also zero vector and then both spheres will be positioned in zero vector.